# Image database build in Oracle - Is an e-commerce style interface workable?

Tags: java, oracle

### Question

Can I build a image database/library that has an e-commerce style checkout system and a powerful search in Oracle/Java? Are there existing elements out there I should be aware of? Or, is this better in another dev environment like PHP/MySQL?

### Overview

I am working on an image database/library dev team on the UI side of things, but I can't help but feel the team is tracking a bit off course on this one.

Ordinarily, I would look to see this entirely within an open-source, license-free environment like a PHP/MySQL/Apache server environment, however strict IT approvals processes have limited the areas of exploration to Oracle as the DB component with Java then making the likely programming environment.

With that noted, I have never worked with either, and don't know how complicated it would be to put the following features together:

- keyword and metadata based search
- e-commerce style checkout system (no payment methods or infrastructure required)
- gallery groupings of images (edited by a central editor)
- tag cloud generation and search
- component to parse metadata from embedded metadata (in XMP) to the database
- web-based back end for database management, maintenance of controlled keyword lists and administration of content

I've uploaded a pdf of screenshots of the UI I've developed for the web side of things.

[UI Sceenshots](http://www.chlorophylldesign.com/mambo/MMLPreviews%5bscreen%5d.pdf)

Sorry for the complicated Q, having a hard time with it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems your question is really a struggle between Oracle/Java and PHP/MySQL.  The details you state are none too difficult to implement using either of these tools sets or using a dozen others that I could think of.

If I am correct (only you could know), then this is a fabulous opportunity for you.  You seem to have experience with the free/open tools, but none with the commercial/closed ones.  Then take the opportunity to learn on your employer's dime.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment on whether Jave is apropriate, but you might look at the Oracle Application Express environment http://apex.oracle.com. This looks and sounds entirely within the scope that they aim for there.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks **David** and **dacracot** for your insights.

Upon further review and consultation (plus some leveraging) of our IT department, considering that this app and DB would run on their own server, and apparently other areas of the corporation have approved the use of open server technologies like PHP, SQL and Apache, this will likely move to a PHP/SQL build for a few reasons, not the least of them being licensing costs of putting Oracle on a new server and the overall larger availability of PHP/SQL developers in the local dev community.

I did adapt some of **dacracot's** advice however, and convinced admin to send me to some .NET training so I can better assist in managing our intranet. I will also keep the **Oracle Application Express** site in mind for further dev needs across our intranet.

Thanks for your help.